# How Wikipedia render infobox

Tags: wikipedia, infobox, wikitext

How Wikipedia convert wikitext of infobox to display on web page?

For example, [Barack Obama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack_Obama)'s wiki, when `View source`, we can see `{{Infobox officeholder` template, and below is snippet of this infobox

```
|birth_name = Barack Hussein Obama II
|birth_date = {{birth date and age|mf=yes|1961|8|4}}
|birth_place = [[Honolulu]], [[Hawaii]], U.S.
|nationality = American
|party = [[Democratic Party (United States)|Democratic]]
```

What I'm interesting is that how Wikipedia display `nationality` as `Nationality` on web page

also `party` as `Political party`

`birth_name`, `birth_date`, `birth_place` as `Born`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is made through the [template Infobox officeholder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Infobox_officeholder). If you look at [the source](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Template:Infobox_officeholder&action=edit), you can see how the code is constructed.

Comment: I'm still not able to figure out how `birth_name`, `birth_date`, `birth_place` display as `Born`. Search [the source](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Template:Infobox_officeholder&action=edit), `Born` not found.

Comment: That is because the template include another template, there you can find it: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Template:Infobox_officeholder/Personal_data&action=edit